# Nested form for has many :through join model, where join model has additional attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models connected through a join model. The join model stores an additional attribute `value`, which is a boolean A `Role` has many `Permissions` through `RolePermission`, and `RolePermission` stores whether that `Role` can perform the action indicated by that `Permission`.

Every `Role` should have a `RolePermission` record for every `Permission` (of which there are ~10).

I'm having trouble creating my form, however. I want there to be a checkbox for each `Permission`, which is used to indicate the boolean value of the `value` attribute for `RolePermission`.

models

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :role_permissions, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :permissions, through: :role_permissions

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :role_permissions
end

class RolePermission < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :role
    belongs_to :permission
end

class Permission < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :role_permissions
    has_many :roles, through: :role_permissions
end
```

table columns

```
Roles
    name: string
    description: string

Permissions
    name: string
    description: string

RolePermissions
    role: references
    permission: references
    value: boolean
```

views/roles/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@chronicle, @role], url: url do |f| %>

    ...

    <%= f.fields_for :role_permissions, Permission.all do |ff| %>
      ???
      <%= ff.label :name %>
      <%= ff.check_box :value %>
      ???
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit text, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block' %>
<% end %>
```

controllers/roles_controller.rb

```
class RolesController < ApplicationController
    ...

    def create
      @chronicle = Chronicle.find(params[:chronicle_id])
      @role = @chronicle.roles.build(role_params)
      ???
      @role_permissions = @role.role_permissions.build
      ???

      if @chronicle.save
        flash[:success] = 'Role successfully created.'
        redirect_to chronicle_role_url(@chronicle, @role)
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

    private
        def role_params
          params.require(:role).permit(:name, :description, role_permission_attributes: [] )
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still believe in the concept without the Role_permission model in the middle. Each role should have their own permissions (has_many), **but the permission name and description are being reused when each role has their permission created.**

Here is what i did.

I created a hash with the values for name and description in the private section of the role-controller

```
# roles_controller.rb
def permission_values
  {
    "Can edit" => "This is not good if you want to party", 
    "Can show" => "Yes, yes, yes. Go ahead",
    "Can hike" => "Oh my! A hike-role?",
    "And so on" => "What do we have here?"
  }     
end
```

Then when i create the Role and the permissions i use `.build` with the permission_values.

*Couldn't do it with seeds.rb because the Role has to be created before assigning permissions*

```
#roles_controller.rb
def new
@role = Role.new
  permission_values.each do |titel, desc| 
    @role.permissions.build(name: titel, description: desc)
  end
end
```

And in the form i use `.object` and `.hidden_field` to show and create the values.

```
# _form.html.erb
...
<%= f.fields_for :permissions do |ff|%>
<h4><%= ff.object.name %></h4>
<%= ff.hidden_field :name %>
<p><%= ff.object.description %></p>
<%= ff.hidden_field :description %>
<%= ff.check_box :permitted %>
<% end %>
```

#### And there you have it!

Now each user will have the same permissions displayed, but they can check permitted if they want and save it with their Role. 
In the show, something like:

```
# show.html.erb
# I would make a helper-method
# And some index-symbol-power!
<%= "Hey! I'm permitted to do this!" if @role.permissions.find_by_name("Can 
edit").permitted? %>
```

**Note:**

*Remember the :id in the permission_attributes in the role_params, so the permissions doesn't duplicate on edit.*

========================================================================

Comment: What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Is the RolePermission model necessary?

Let me know if i have misunderstood something. Why not put a boolean attribute on the Permission model?

table columns:

```
Roles
name: string
description: string

Permissions
referenced: role
name: string
description: string
permitted: boolean
```

Now you can have a checkbox field in the field_for without any problems

```
#In form_for [@chronicle, @role], url: url do |f|  
...
<%= f.fields_for :permissions do |ff| %>
 <%= ff.label :permitted %>
 <%= ff.check_box :permitted %>
 ... <!-- description and name -->
```

And your controller

*Remember not to call Permission.all in the view, but use .build in the action new in the RolesController.*

```
def new
#Find @chronicle
@role = Role.new
10.times { @role.permissions.build }
end

def create 
# If you set up your accepts_nested_attributes_for :permissions 
# (delete the rest of role_permission stuff) in role.rb, 
# and update your role_params with the permission_attributes everything should 
be 
# working fine. Find your role and save it. 
end
```

And then you can do something like:

```
if role.permissions.first.permitted? 
# DO SOMETHING CRAZY
end
```

---

Comment: I'm unsure about this because I want to have 10 or so constant Permissions I can reuse across Roles.

Say there are three Permissions: `Can View`, `Can Edit`, and `Can Create`.

The `Role` admin may have `RolePermissions` where the value for all three is `true`.

The `Role` Moderator may have `RolePermissions` where `Can View` is `true`, `Can Create` is `true`, but `Can Edit` is `false`.

Et cetera.

It just doesn't seem particularly clean to store that info in the `Roles` table.

Comment: are you creating a login-system from scratch? With role-based authorization?
If you are, i would look into the [devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)<br>
Here you can create the authorization in the top of each controller, for example: 
`access all: [:show, :index], user: {except: [:destroy]}, site_admin: :all`

Of course you can create it your self, but using Devise for me feels like a timesaver each time.

Comment: Not really applicable here. I'm using Sorcery for user authentication, but the Roles and their RolePermissions (but not Permissions) are user-created. So CanCanCan/Pundit/Devise don't really fit my use case. And anyway, this is a hobby project for getting my feet wet with Rails -- I'd rather roll my own authorization, etc. to help me learn instead of just plugging in a gem.

Comment: Yeah okay. I see :) Good idea. 
I will give it another try - to sec.